Integral of a multivalued function
I need to calculate this integral using complex analysis methods
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\,\sqrt[4]{\,{x^{3}\left(1 - x\right)}\,}\,}{x + 1}\,{\rm d}x
$$
I encountered a problem: I received an inadequate response $-\sqrt[4]{8}\pi$. I don't understand what could be wrong.
I consider the function in the complex plane
$$
f(z) = e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\sqrt[4]{x^3(x - 1)}}{x + 1},
$$
which is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \backslash [0, 1]$ (took the main branch from the root).
By choosing a suitable contour and calculating the function on the upper and lower banks, I arrived at the equality
$$
I(e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}} - e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}})e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}} = 2\pi i \text{res}_{-1}f,
$$
where $I$ the required integral.
Calculating I, I get the answer I wrote above. What could be the error?
Thank you in advance

Let
$$
x = \frac{t}{1 + t}
$$
Then
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sqrt[4]{x^3(1 - x)}dx}{x + 1} = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{t^{\frac{3}{4}}dt}{(2t + 1)(t + 1)^2}.
$$
It is already easy to calculate such an integral
Answer: $\sqrt{2} \pi\Big{(}2 - \Big{(}\frac{3}{4} + \sqrt[4]{2}\Big{)}$
